# jquery mobile vmousemove smooth when it wants

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, drag

jQuery Mobile vmousemove event only gets fired when I press the tablet, and when the drag is done. No events actual move events are fired.

On the other if I start a swipe, then everything works fine. But since I am implementing a vertical drag, it is annoying to have to start dragging horizontally to go to move vertically.

Also, if I remove the swipe event, then there is no way that the drag event gets fired while I move my fingers.

I have this:

```
$('body').bind('swiperight',function(){
    previous();
});
$('body').bind('swipeleft',function(){
    next();
});
```

and this:

```
function handleDrag(e) {
    $('h1').html(e.pageY);
}
$('.image img').bind('vmousedown', function(e){
    $('body').bind('vmousemove', handleDrag);
});
$('body').bind('vmnouseup', function(){
$('.image').unbind('vmousemove', handleDrag);
});
```

Comment: This did the trick:

    $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = -1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'vmnouseup' should be 'vmouseup'